# Can I convert a string field with space delimiter into array in mongoDB aggregate

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, aggregate, field

I would like to convert a document with a string like this :

```
{ myField : 'bar foo boo' }
```

Into something like this :

```
{ myField : ['bar', 'foo', 'boo'] }
```

using space as delimiter.
Is it possible with aggregate or should I do it programmatically ?

Comment: I believe you should do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) operator. It's run inside an aggregation stage. In this example
we make a new field using the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage. To pick a specific document put a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage at the front of your aggregation pipeline.

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.test.insert({ myField : 'bar foo boo' })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.aggregate([{"$project" :{ "mySplitField" :{"$split" : ["$myField", " "]}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebe77d0ca404d65eed0c4a8"), "mySplitField" : [ "bar", "foo", "boo" ] }
>
```